# Get one element to scroll for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

[FIDDLE!!](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/9GDnp/)

How would I go about getting `#Index3` to scroll for all of the `.group`s? There will always be the same number of `li`s in each `.group`. Can I get the scroll position with jQuery and set it onto the other elements even if the have `overflow: hidden;`?

Comment: yes you can, do that.

Comment: Include your code in your question. It's not OK for your question to require us to open links to external code-hosting services. Fiddles may *supplement* questions, but they shouldn't be your *entire* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can do exactly what you proposed...](http://jsfiddle.net/9GDnp/1/)

```
$('#Index3').on('scroll', function() {
   $('.group').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()); 
});
```